# URL Rewrite (Joomla 2.5)

Tags: .htaccess, joomla2.5

Good morning,

I would like to rewrite my URL in my Joomla 2.5.

Change this:
http://www.idermo.es/index.php?option=com_content&view=article&id=119&Itemid=999

Into:
http://www.idermo.es/custom

Is it possible with the htcaccess file?

Regards,

Thanks,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is one of the basic joomla functions. You have to rename via ftp htaccess.txt to .htaccess in your joomla root directory and set:

```
System -> Global Configuration -> Search Engine Friendly Urls: Yes
System -> Global Configuration -> Use Url Rewriting: Yes
```

Then you have to connect your article into a menu item and set the alias to the value that your link want to be.

Good Luck!